# Suspicious Behavior From ListView.getItems().removeAll()

Tags: java, list, generics, user-interface, javafx

If I have a list containing 4 objects(not all the same), and I call JavaFX's`listView.getItems().removeAll(listView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems())` with a single object (let's say number 1) selected, objects 2 and 3 will be removed as well. Is this the normal operation for `removeAll()`? It led to a rather frustrating bug. This was not documented in the `removeAll()` method, and is rather misleading because I used it since it has better type-safety than the normal `remove` method, which takes an `Object`.

Comment: Make sure that you have correctly implemented `equals()` for the type of items within the listView.

Comment: @Eng.Fouad `equals` and `hashcode` have been overriden already. They were different objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you remove a selected item, the selection will be updated so that some other item will be selected. When the selection is updated, this has the side effect of updating the list returned by `listView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems()`. This interacts badly with the `List.removeAll` method.

Suppose we have `targetList.removeAll(removeList)`. What happens is that for each element in `targetList`, the code asks, "does this element appear in `removeList`?" If it does, the element is removed from `targetList`. This has a side effect on `removeList`, which changes the behavior the next time around the loop.

More specifically:

1. This starts off with element 0. Since this element doesn't appear in `removeList`, nothing happens.
2. Next is element 1. Since it's selected, it appears in `removeList`, so element 1 is removed. The `ListView` code detects that the selected element has been removed, so it updates the selection to element 2. This means that `removeList` **now contains element 2**.
3. Next is element 2. Since it's selected, it appears in `removeList`, so element 2 is removed. The `ListView` code detects that the selected element has been removed, so it updates the selection to element 3. This means that `removeList` **now contains element 3**.
4. I think you can see what's happening now. :-)

Probably the easiest way around this is to copy the selection list before passing it to `removeAll`:

```
list.getItems().removeAll(new ArrayList<>(list.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems()));
```

Comment: Wow, that's crazy. The first time that it happened, I was surprised. I guess that's a part of the learning curve.

Comment: @SarahSzabo Yes it's part of the learning curve, but frankly the API smells a bit to me. From the pure collections point of view, `List.removeAll(list2)` expects that list2 doesn't change for the duration of the call. But the `ObservableList` returned from `MultipleSelectionModel.getSelectedItems` is always kept up-to-date with respect to the selection. So if you want to use the current selection as part of a computation that updates the selection -- which seems entirely reasonable -- you get into trouble.