# List.size() says 3, but forEach() executes twice

Tags: java-8

I have a List (technically, it's an ObservableList from the JavaFX API) that has three elements in it. I've verified the contents using both .size() and a debugger. However, when I call list.forEach(), my Consumer is only run twice. What might cause that?

Comment: Hey, I know this guy! As user3486184 says, you might be removing elements from the list while iterating it. More likely, I'd think, is that since it's an ObservableList, something *else* might be observing it and creating side effects. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/23986364/1441122 for an example of how this can get you into trouble. We'd have to see the code to be sure, though.

Comment: Hey, Stuart! I was actually going to tweet this link to you. :) Thanks for chiming in (and, of course, user3486184). I absolutely was mutating the collection in the lambda. I'll ground myself later, but I need to fix that first. :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That can happen if you're removing elements from the list while you're iterating over it. If that's the case, make a copy of the list, iterate over that, and remove elements from the original.